# Haskell - writing a little parser

Tags: parsing, haskell

I want to write a little parser for soccer scores.

For example the input `"0:2"` should be parsed to `Just (Score 0 2)`. If there is something like `"3:3"` it should give me `"Nothing"`. Everything else should be give me `"Nothing"`, too.

```
data Score = Score Int Int
deriving (Eq,Show,Ord)


runParsec :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
runParsec parser input = case runP parser () "" input of
Left  _ -> Nothing
Right a -> Just a
```

The parser that I give the runParsec as an argument looks until now like this:

```
parseScore :: Parser Score
parseScore str1 = case str1 of
    "x:y" && (x /= y)   -> Right Score x y
    Otherwise           -> Left x
```

I know, that this code for parseScore is unable to work. Because I cannot pattern match with a String like "x:y". But how can I solve this problem?

`runParsec parseScore "0:2"` should give me `Just (Score 0 2)`

I'm thankful for hints.

Thanks!

Comment: `3:3` should give you `Score 3 3` or `Nothing` ?

Comment: Nothing. 

"5:1" - Just (Score 5 1) / "3:3" - Nothing. / "urhfuhergu" - Nothing.

Comment: Why should `3:3` be `Nothing` when it's a valid score?

Comment: It's just for me to learn how I can do sth like this. It's no practical tool, it's just for myself as an excercise.

Comment: I think you mean `Just (Score 3 0)`, not `Just "Score 3 0"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write a proper `Parser` for your type and filter out the things you don't need:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char

data Score = Score Int Int deriving (Show)

parseScore :: Parser Score
parseScore = do
  a <- integer
  char ':'
  b <- integer
  return $ Score a b

integer :: Parser Int
integer = read <$> many1 digit

runParsec :: String -> Maybe Score
runParsec input = case parse parseScore "" input of
  Left e -> Nothing
  Right e -> case e of
    Score 0 2 -> Just e
    _ -> Nothing
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> runParsec "0:2"
Just (Score 0 2)
λ> runParsec "3:3"
Nothing
λ> runParsec "3:4"
Nothing
```

> What can I do, if I want to accept all scores, 1:0, 0:4 and so on?
>   Everything, but no random input like "jirjgir" and no equal scores
>   like "2:2" or "5:5"

Just change your filtering conditions:

```
runParsec :: String -> Maybe Score
runParsec input = case parse parseScore "" input of
  Left e -> Nothing
  Right e -> case e of
    Score x y -> if x == y
                 then Nothing
                 else Just e
```

Demo:

```
λ> runParsec "1:0"
Just (Score 1 0)
λ> runParsec "0:4"
Just (Score 0 4)
λ> runParsec "2:2"
Nothing
λ> runParsec "jiraf"
Nothing
```

Comment: bikeshedding: why not just `integer :: Parser Int; integer = read <$> many1 digit`. Replace a local definition with a global type signature.

Comment: @rampion I think it's still a global definition. I haven't added the type signature. Will update it to include the type signature.

Comment: I meant the local definition of `rd`

Comment: @rampion Thanks, I see that now. :) Updated it appropriately.

Comment: What can I do, if I want to accept all scores, 1:0, 0:4 and so on? Everything, but no random input like "jirjgir" and no equal scores like "2:2" or "5:5"..

Comment: @fuuman Just write the appropriate filtering conditions in `runParsec`. De let me know if you want to see an example of it, I will update the answer.

Comment: Yeah, a example would be awesome :) Thank you! I dont know how to check if x == y..

Comment: Thank you! Now I want to write the unparser. Next problems will be appear :D